# Existing Maven Project on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to migrate my existing Maven project to Amazon Beanstalk.

Looking at amazon's documentation,i don't see any maven project deployment instructions.

I tried to upload the war file generated but the application is not coming up on beanstalk.

1. I would like to know if there is any existing documentation to
   deploy on beanstalk from maven.
2. I have Spring Data JPA,Spring MVC application,do i need to do specific configuration or move configuration files from  within the WAR file.

Comment: Don't make two questions in the same question, makes it harder to moderate and vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the maven plugin, check beanstalk-maven-plugin at http://beanstalker.ingenieux.com.br/beanstalk-maven-plugin/, it is has a lot of nice features, like removing old versions, incremental fast deploys and many others.

Also, check the EB log files in /var/log/eb-cloud-init.log to find out why your app is not coming up, you will probably find that you need some customization, like download your JDBC driver and configure your datasource. For that you can use elastic beanstalk configuration files like this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

And post again if you have more specific issues. Best of luck with beanstalk!

Comment: This works for me!!!
FYI ,what i did in another case was the following,The project was bundled into the war file using the maven build.I uploaded this war file using the Beanstalk console.The properties file and persistence were inside the war.I put the correct values in them before uploading.Voila it worked :)
this approach is especially useful i think ,if it's a legacy project being migrated to Beanstalk and we cannot develop it from ground up.this lets me take the benefit of beanstalk web server scaling without touching my current DB server and dev setup

Comment: btw, there's a specific archetype for 'wrapper' webapps:

mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=elasticbeanstalk-wrapper